# Single quotes vs double quotes

Tags: ruby, string, escaping, quotes, double-quotes

I am trying to split a string by three consecutive newlines (`"\n\n\n"`). I was trying `str.split('\n\n\n')` and it didn't work, but when I changed to `str.split("\n\n\n")`, it started to work. Could anyone explain to me why such behaviour happens?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

String in single quotes is a **raw** string. So `'\n\n\n'` is three backslashes and three `n`, not three line feeds as you expected. Only double quotes string can be escaped correctly.

```
puts 'abc\nabc'  # => abc\nabc
puts "abc\nabc"  # => abc
                 #    abc
```

Answer (score 5):

Single quoted string have the actual/literal contents, e.g.

```
1.9.3-p194 :003 > puts 'Hi\nThere'
Hi\nThere
 => nil
```

Whereas double-quoted string 'interpolate' the special characters (\n) and do the line feed, e.g.

```
1.9.3-p194 :004 > puts "Hi\nThere"
Hi
There
 => nil 
1.9.3-p194 :005 >
```

Best practice Recommendations:

- Choose single quotes over double quotes when possible (use double quotes as needed for interpolation).
- When nesting 'Quotes inside "quotes" somewhere' put the double ones inside the single quotes

Answer (score 0):

In single-quoted string literals, backslashes need not be doubled

```
'\n' == '\\n'
```